# How to use both my dual internet connections in the same exact moment on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, networking, wireless-networking, download

I am running Mac OS X and I have two different Internet connections on two different local networks: One is wireless and the other is wired. I want to use both on the same time to get higher download bandwidth. I saw Nvidia has something like that called “[NVIDIA DualNet with Teaming Advanced Networking.](http://www.nvidia.com/content/nforce5/TB-02499-001_v01_DualNet.pdf)”

So can I download using my two networks in the same time if the download server allows it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and no. The download server WILL allow it, because you're making requests from two different IPs.

There is a way, but here's what you need:

- Two different connections
- Two routers on **different** subnets (ex: `192.168.1.0/24` and `192.168.2.0/24`)
- Speedify on the Unlimited plan for unlimited bandwidth.

OK, once you have these, here's what you do:

1. Set one router up for ethernet only, and on the .1.0/24 subnet
2. Set the other router up for WiFi, and on the other subnet, .2.0/24
3. Download and install Speedify
4. Connect your OS X machine (10.8+) to both Wifi AND ethernet
5. Launch Speedify
6. Done.

Comment: Speedify rocks!

Comment: its a paid service, and have advantage if you have more than 2-3 internet sources.